# Serialization and file size

Tags: java, serialization, byte

When I serialize a file object (whose size on the hard drive is `3,404,851`  bytes) using `org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils` such as :

```
File fileObject = new File(path);
byte[] fileBuffer = SerializationUtils.serialize(fileObject);
```

The `fileBuffer.length` returns `91`! Shouldn't it be rather `3,404,851` ?

Comment: The utility only serializes the object which points to a file, not the entire file.

Comment: You're not serializing the contents of the file. The `File` class just represents the file on disk; so it probably contains the filename and maybe a few other things.

Answer (score 1):

You're serializing the `File` object, not the file itself.

The `File` object contains just a few fields describing the file and its location, not the entire file contents.

Comment: how may I please achieve that in this case?

Comment: 1. That's a separate question
2. What are your trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to serialize the content of an audio file that I will frame then into UDP packets.

Comment: What do you mean by "serialize"? The file is already serialized by definition.

Comment: @sasuke Do you just mean you want to have the contents of the file as a `byte[]`? Because that can be done pretty easily with any of Java's classes designed for reading files.

Comment: @Kevin exactly that is what i meant. Thanks for pointing it out. I found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the serialization documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/serialized-form.html#java.io.File) you can notice that the serialization util only saves the path of the file (with the original separator which is converted while deserializing if needed), rather than its content.

In case of Oracle documentation refer to "See also" section of javadoc to get a link to description of the serialized form.